# Could my upvotes be removed?

Tags: support, up-votes

If I click on someone's profile and scroll through their questions/answers posted and upvote a lot of them, can this be removed as looking suspicious or spammy?  I know this happens with downvotes, but does it apply to upvotes as well?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise you could create a new fake account and go through your main profile or ask a buddy to upvote all of your stuff. That's voting fraud and will be rolled back when the system detects unsual voting patterns. Going through the profile of someone and upvoting many of their posts can trigger this. The details are unknown though, so no further information about the exact definition of "unusual" available. A handful is probably fine, if you spend all your daily votes they are likely to be reversed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Applies to upvotes. (disclosure - I am a Mod at [Money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/)) Some time ago, soon after I got my diamond, I saw activity from a member offering edits. These came in as items that needed to be voted on, or approved by a mod. The member was within 100pts of rep to have the privilege to edit with no need for approval. I searched on his profile and "serial-upvoted" 10 answers of his. The next day, I saw he still needed his edits approved as my upvotes were detected and cancelled. The system cannot detect motivation, so my 'good intentions' didn't negate the fact that I tripped an internal process intended to detect fraudulent voting.